# Reading UNIX file properties via C# over NFS

Tags: c#, unix, nfs

i have two servers.

1. solaris 10 acts as a NFS server
2. win 2003 ernterprise server with installed UNIX/NFS extensions acts as a NFS client

The win 2003 server has mounted one share of the solaris system. How can i check (via C#) the origin UNIX file properties (e.g.: `-rw-r--r--`) of a remote file located on the NFS share?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are at the mercy of the NFS client. Refer to its documentation to see if there is a developer API that allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can check my project, I have developed some windows libraries in order to use NFS v2/v3 over C# .net

http://code.google.com/p/nekodrive